# How do I alter a variable with a uicontrol callback function?

Tags: matlab, callback

The big picture goal is to successively plot an image sequence at some rate and pause the process when the pushbutton is pressed. Then resume the process upon hitting the space bar or pressing the pushbutton or whatever. Here is the code I have so far with a simple `rand/pause(0.5)` procedure for each iteration of the loop (instead of plotting my images).

My issue is this:
`ButtonCallback` seems to be invoked when the pushbutton is pressed, and `DoPause` is set to 1 in the callback function, BUT `DoPause` is not changed in the main function `PauseButtonTest`. How do I change this variable so the `if` statement in my `while` loop is executed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
function PauseButtonTest

  DoPause = 0;

  hb = uicontrol('Style','Pushbutton','String','Pause','FontWeight','Bold', ...
    'Callback',@ButtonCallback,'Unit','Normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1]);

  while ishandle(hb)

    if DoPause
      disp('You pushed the button')
      pause
      DoPause = 0;
      set(hb,'Enable','On')
      drawnow
    end

    % Computations/Plot successive figures/etc.
    rand
    pause(0.5)

  end

end


function ButtonCallback(hObj, event)

  DoPause = 1;
  disp('You are in ButtonCallback')
  disp(['DoPause = ' num2str(DoPause)])
  set(hObj,'Enable','off')

end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Nested functions.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)

Just move `function ButtonCallback(hObj, event) ...` inside `PauseButtonTest` so that it has access to its variables ("externally scoped" variables).  Plop it down a couple of lines below the `while` loop and before the `end` that signals the end of `PauseButtonTest`.